# Plot Multibeam bathymetry grid

Tags: geodesy

I don't speak *Mathematica* very well, but I am sure I could do great things with this programming language!

I will delete this question if it is a duplicate, but I will be glad if you could point me to previous questions which could be useful to my problem.

I have a swathsounding bathymetric survey (Multibeam) grid made of geographic longitude-latitude coordinates and water depth. The grid has Dimensions {368543, 3} and this is a small sample in deep water:

```
DataGeo = 
  {{89.5121, 21.1997, -457.58}, {89.5126, 21.1997, -458.11}, 
   {89.5131, 21.1997, -460.12}}
```

In addition, this is a larger sample in deep water:

```
            DataGeoLdeep={{89.5492, 21.1988, -118.73}, {89.5497, 21.1988,-118.25}, {89.5502,21.1988, -117.84}, {89.5507, 21.1988, -117.39},{89.5512,21.1988, -116.78}, {89.5516, 21.1988, -116.12}, {89.5521,21.1988, -115.49}, {89.5526, 21.1988, -114.91}, {89.5531,21.1988, -114.37}, {89.5536, 21.1988, -113.84}, {89.554,21.1988, -113.42}, {89.5545, 21.1988, -113.02}, {89.6485,21.1988, -84.73}, {89.649, 21.1988, -84.68}, {89.6495,21.1988, -84.64}, {89.6499, 21.1988, -84.58}, {89.6504,21.1988, -84.53}, {89.6509, 21.1988, -84.48}, {89.6514,21.1988, -84.44}, {89.6519, 21.1988, -84.4}, {89.6523,21.1988, -84.36}, {89.6528, 21.1988, -84.3}, {89.6533,21.1988, -84.3}, {89.6538, 21.1988, -84.44}, {89.6543,21.1988, -84.62}, {89.6548, 21.1988, -84.16}, {89.6552,21.1988, -84.11}, {89.6557, 21.1988, -84.09}, {89.6562,21.1988, -84.08}, {89.6567, 21.1988, -84.08}, {89.6572,21.1988, -84.07}, {89.6576, 21.1988, -84.06}, {89.6581,21.1988, -84.06}, {89.674, 21.1988, -82.13}, {89.6745,21.1988, -82.38}, {89.675, 21.1988, -82.5}, {89.6755,21.1988, -82.61}, {89.676, 21.1988, -82.8}, {89.6764,21.1988, -83.12}, {89.6769, 21.1988, -83.57}, {89.6774,21.1988, -83.34}, {89.6779, 21.1988, -76.8}, {89.6784,21.1988, -78.08}, {89.6788, 21.1988, -75.23}, {89.6793,21.1988, -83.22}, {89.6798, 21.1988, -80.08}, {89.6803,21.1988, -79.91}, {89.6808, 21.1988, -80.3}, {89.6813,21.1988, -80.63}, {89.6817, 21.1988, -80.86}, {89.6822,21.1988, -81.02}, {89.6827, 21.1988, -81.17}, {89.2813,21.1993, -464.33}, {89.2818, 21.1993, -464.58}, {89.2823,21.1993, -464.89}, {89.2828, 21.1993, -465.16}, {89.2833,21.1993, -465.34}, {89.2837, 21.1993, -465.4}, {89.2842,21.1993, -465.3}, {89.2847, 21.1993, -464.99}, {89.2852,21.1993, -470.99}, {89.2857, 21.1993, -476.47}, {89.2861,21.1993, -480.33}, {89.2866, 21.1993, -482.66}, {89.2871,21.1993, -485.41}, {89.2876, 21.1993, -487.76}, {89.2881,21.1993, -488.97}, {89.2886, 21.1993, -491.39}, {89.289,21.1993, -493.92}, {89.2895, 21.1993, -494.64}, {89.29,21.1993, -497.22}, {89.2905, 21.1993, -499.43}, {89.291,21.1993, -496.97}, {89.2914, 21.1993, -501.09}, {89.2919,21.1993, -500.69}, {89.2924, 21.1993, -505.04}, {89.2929,21.1993, -504.92}, {89.2934, 21.1993, -501.92}, {89.2939,21.1993, -497.31}, {89.2943, 21.1993, -496.91}, {89.2948,21.1993, -505.4}, {89.2953, 21.1993, -505.93}, {89.2958,21.1993, -497.57}, {89.2963, 21.1993, -480.98}, {89.2967,21.1993, -481.8}, {89.2972, 21.1993, -487.51}, {89.2977,21.1993, -490.94}, {89.2982, 21.1993, -492.11}, {89.2987,21.1993, -492.99}, {89.2992, 21.1993, -495.18}, {89.2996,21.1993, -498.41}, {89.3001, 21.1993, -500.36}, {89.3006,21.1993, -501.09}, {89.3011, 21.1993, -501.41}, {89.3016,21.1993, -503.89}, {89.302, 21.1993, -503.88}, {89.3025,21.1993, -501.72}, {89.303, 21.1993, -501.11}, {89.3035,21.1993, -502.15}, {89.304, 21.1993, -502.15}, {89.3045,21.1993, -501.88}, {89.3049, 21.1993, -502.69}, {89.3054,21.1993, -503.18}, {89.3059, 21.1993, -503.59}, {89.3064,21.1993, -504.02}, {89.3069, 21.1993, -504.47}, {89.3073,21.1993, -504.9}, {89.3078, 21.1993, -505.29}, {89.3546,21.1993, -538.43}, {89.355, 21.1993, -539.47}, {89.3555,21.1993, -540.25}, {89.356, 21.1993, -541.02}, {89.3565,21.1993, -541.84}, {89.357, 21.1993, -542.79}, {89.3575,21.1993, -544.06}, {89.3579, 21.1993, -546.38}, {89.3584,21.1993, -545.25}, {89.3589, 21.1993, -545.71}, {89.3594,21.1993, -545.11}, {89.3599, 21.1993, -546.12}, {89.3603,21.1993, -549.26}, {89.3608, 21.1993, -549.2}, {89.3613,21.1993, -548.09}, {89.3618, 21.1993, -547.29}, {89.3623,21.1993, -547.94}, {89.3628, 21.1993, -547.22}, {89.3632,21.1993, -548.04}, {89.3637, 21.1993, -546.3}, {89.3642,21.1993, -546.65}, {89.3647, 21.1993, -544.22}, {89.3652,21.1993, -545.03}, {89.3656, 21.1993, -544.74}, {89.3661,21.1993, -541.21}, {89.3666, 21.1993, -539.93}, {89.3671,21.1993, -541.32}, {89.3676, 21.1993, -544.28}, {89.3681,21.1993, -540.58}, {89.3685, 21.1993, -539.06}, {89.369,21.1993, -537.31}, {89.3695, 21.1993, -533.89}, {89.37,21.1993, -534.03}, {89.3705, 21.1993, -534.07}, {89.3709,21.1993, -536.93}, {89.3714, 21.1993, -535.34}, {89.3719,21.1993, -535.49}, {89.3724, 21.1993, -535.46}, {89.3729,21.1993, -535.1}, {89.3734, 21.1993, -534.34}, {89.3738,21.1993, -532.14}, {89.3743, 21.1993, -531.97}, {89.3748,21.1993, -533.03}, {89.3753, 21.1993, -535.21}, {89.3758,21.1993, -533.45}, {89.3762, 21.1993, -532.38}, {89.3767,21.1993, -531.5}, {89.3772, 21.1993, -529.94}, {89.3777,21.1993, -530.27}, {89.3782, 21.1993, -531.43}, {89.3787,21.1993, -531.31}, {89.3791, 21.1993, -530.94}, {89.3796,21.1993, -530.16}, {89.3801, 21.1993, -530.19}, {89.3806,21.1993, -531.52}, {89.3811, 21.1993, -530.67}, {89.3815,21.1993, -524.64}, {89.382, 21.1993, -520.97}, {89.3825,21.1993, -517.2}, {89.383, 21.1993, -513.64}, {89.3835,21.1993, -510.7}, {89.384, 21.1993, -510.64}, {89.3844,21.1993, -510.14}, {89.3849, 21.1993, -506.81}, {89.3854,21.1993, -508.51}, {89.3859, 21.1993, -507.82}, {89.3864,21.1993, -508.37}, {89.3868, 21.1993, -509.25}, {89.3873,21.1993, -509.69}, {89.3878, 21.1993, -509.38}, {89.3883,21.1993, -508.79}, {89.3888, 21.1993, -508.92}, {89.3893,21.1993, -509.23}, {89.3897, 21.1993, -510.75}, {89.3902,21.1993, -511.79}, {89.3907, 21.1993, -511.32}, {89.3912,21.1993, -512.86}, {89.3917, 21.1993, -512.85}, {89.3921,21.1993, -511.95}, {89.3926, 21.1993, -513.42}, {89.3931,21.1993, -512.57}, {89.3936, 21.1993, -516.59}, {89.3941,21.1993, -516.98}, {89.3946, 21.1993, -518.76}, {89.395,21.1993, -517.22}, {89.3955, 21.1993, -514.14}, {89.396,21.1993, -510.71}, {89.3965, 21.1993, -509.96}, {89.397, 21.1993, -510.71}, {89.3974, 21.1993, -510.93}, {89.3979,21.1993, -511.18}, {89.3984, 21.1993, -513.4}, {89.3989,21.1993, -514.81}, {89.3994, 21.1993, -516.9}, {89.3999,21.1993, -516.31}, {89.4003, 21.1993, -515.65}, {89.4008,21.1993, -517.14}, {89.4013, 21.1993, -518.89}, {89.4018,21.1993, -520.44}, {89.4023, 21.1993, -521.84}, {89.4027,21.1993, -521.14}, {89.4032, 21.1993, -519.69}, {89.4037,21.1993, -519.22}, {89.4042, 21.1993, -520.22}, {89.4047,21.1993, -520.69}, {89.4052, 21.1993, -523.48}, {89.4056,21.1993, -526.59}, {89.4061, 21.1993, -529.68}, {89.4066,21.1993, -531.17}, {89.4071, 21.1993, -531.4}, {89.4076,21.1993, -530.42}, {89.408, 21.1993, -530.38}, {89.4085,21.1993, -526.96}, {89.409, 21.1993, -527.49}, {89.4095,21.1993, -528.45}, {89.41, 21.1993, -525.67}, {89.4105,21.1993, -526.77}, {89.4109, 21.1993, -526.77}, {89.4114,21.1993, -529.43}, {89.4119, 21.1993, -529.74}, {89.4124,21.1993, -535.94}, {89.4129, 21.1993, -537.51}, {89.4133,21.1993, -537.97}, {89.4138, 21.1993, -538.85}, {89.4143,21.1993, -539.67}, {89.4148, 21.1993, -539.13}, {89.4153,21.1993, -538.39}, {89.4158, 21.1993, -538.89}, {89.4162,21.1993, -539.83}, {89.4167, 21.1993, -539.51}, {89.4172,21.1993, -540.42}, {89.4177, 21.1993, -540.32}, {89.4182,21.1993, -540.23}, {89.4186, 21.1993, -539.71}, {89.4191,21.1993, -538.12}, {89.4196, 21.1993, -537.62}, {89.4201,21.1993, -538.09}, {89.4206, 21.1993, -537.58}, {89.4211,21.1993, -537.91}, {89.4215, 21.1993, -537.18}, {89.422,21.1993, -537.23}, {89.4225, 21.1993, -537.54}, {89.423,21.1993, -538.04}, {89.4235, 21.1993, -539.16}, {89.4239,21.1993, -536.86}, {89.4244, 21.1993, -536.97}, {89.4249,21.1993, -535.07}, {89.4254, 21.1993, -535.2}, {89.4259,21.1993, -533.94}, {89.4264, 21.1993, -535.13}, {89.4268,21.1993, -533.79}, {89.4273, 21.1993, -532.32}, {89.4278,21.1993, -532.21}, {89.4283, 21.1993, -531.13}, {89.4288,21.1993, -530.37}, {89.4293, 21.1993, -530.48}, {89.4297,21.1993, -530.97}, {89.4302, 21.1993, -532.22}, {89.4307,21.1993, -532.36}, {89.4312, 21.1993, -532.2}, {89.4317,21.1993, -531.71}, {89.4321, 21.1993, -530.47}, {89.4326,21.1993, -531.4}, {89.4331, 21.1993, -533.47}, {89.4336,21.1993, -533.49}, {89.4341, 21.1993, -533.13}, {89.4346,21.1993, -530.04}, {89.435, 21.1993, -530.19}, {89.4355,21.1993, -529.2}, {89.436, 21.1993, -528.78}, {89.4365,21.1993, -529.7}, {89.437, 21.1993, -529.81}, {89.4374,21.1993, -530.48}, {89.4379, 21.1993, -531.95}, {89.4384,21.1993, -529.74}, {89.4389, 21.1993, -530.29}, {89.4394,21.1993, -530.9}, {89.4399, 21.1993, -531.57}, {89.4403,21.1993, -531.86}, {89.4408, 21.1993, -531.19}, {89.4413,21.1993, -531.72}, {89.4418, 21.1993, -531.63}, {89.4423,21.1993, -533.39}, {89.4427, 21.1993, -534.22}, {89.4432,21.1993, -534.28}, {89.4437, 21.1993, -533.44}, {89.4442,21.1993, -533.03}, {89.4447, 21.1993, -535.01}, {89.4452,21.1993, -535.2}, {89.4456, 21.1993, -534.25}, {89.4461,21.1993, -535.25}, {89.4466, 21.1993, -535.35}, {89.4471,21.1993, -536.86}, {89.4476, 21.1993, -537.67}, {89.448,21.1993, -538.13}, {89.4485, 21.1993, -539.32}, {89.449,21.1993, -538.97}, {89.4495, 21.1993, -537.45}, {89.45,21.1993, -535.76}, {89.4505, 21.1993, -533.43}, {89.4509,21.1993, -533.58}, {89.4514, 21.1993, -533.79}, {89.4519,21.1993, -533.25}, {89.4524, 21.1993, -531.29}, {89.4529,21.1993, -529.94}, {89.4533, 21.1993, -529.47}, {89.4538,21.1993, -527.97}, {89.4543, 21.1993, -528.44}, {89.4548,21.1993, -528.96}, {89.4553, 21.1993, -529.06}, {89.4558,21.1993, -528.36}, {89.4562, 21.1993, -527.25}, {89.4567,21.1993, -527.6}, {89.4572, 21.1993, -526.92}, {89.4577,21.1993, -524.89}, {89.4582, 21.1993, -523.94}, {89.4586,21.1993, -523.24}, {89.4591, 21.1993, -521.92}, {89.4596,21.1993, -524.08}, {89.4601, 21.1993, -524.06}, {89.4606,21.1993, -524.54}, {89.4611, 21.1993, -526.13}, {89.4615,21.1993, -525.72}, {89.462, 21.1993, -523.38}, {89.4625,21.1993, -521.53}, {89.463, 21.1993, -520.89}, {89.4635,21.1993, -518.51}, {89.4639, 21.1993, -518.72}, {89.4644,21.1993, -519.46}, {89.4649, 21.1993, -521.16}, {89.4654,21.1993, -519.39}, {89.4659, 21.1993, -518.65}, {89.4664,21.1993, -517.87}, {89.4668, 21.1993, -518.73}, {89.4673,21.1993, -520.23}, {89.4678, 21.1993, -522.98}, {89.4683,21.1993, -522.45}, {89.4688, 21.1993, -520.91}, {89.4692,21.1993, -519.46}, {89.4697, 21.1993, -520.15}, {89.4702,21.1993, -519.38}, {89.4707, 21.1993, -519.34}, {89.4712,21.1993, -519.33}, {89.4717, 21.1993, -520.02}, {89.4721,21.1993, -524.54}, {89.4726, 21.1993, -523.79}, {89.4731,21.1993, -524.23}, {89.4736, 21.1993, -521.79}, {89.4741,21.1993, -519.99}, {89.4745, 21.1993, -519.69}, {89.475,21.1993, -521.09}, {89.4755, 21.1993, -520.47}, {89.476,21.1993, -521.}, {89.4765, 21.1993, -520.51}, {89.477,21.1993, -518.41}, {89.4774, 21.1993, -518.22}, {89.4779,21.1993, -517.1}, {89.4784, 21.1993, -517.65}, {89.4789,21.1993, -517.67}, {89.4794, 21.1993, -518.36}, {89.4798,21.1993, -518.7}, {89.4803, 21.1993, -516.64}, {89.4808,21.1993, -513.83}, {89.4813, 21.1993, -509.46}, {89.4818,21.1993, -509.15}, {89.4823, 21.1993, -508.94}, {89.4827,21.1993, -508.22}, {89.4832, 21.1993, -507.75}, {89.4837,21.1993, -508.42}, {89.4842, 21.1993, -507.35}, {89.4847,21.1993, -505.64}, {89.4851, 21.1993, -505.01}, {89.4856,21.1993, -502.44}, {89.4861, 21.1993, -501.8}, {89.4866,21.1993, -501.32}, {89.4871, 21.1993, -501.38}, {89.4876,21.1993, -503.31}, {89.488, 21.1993, -501.44}, {89.4885,21.1993, -500.77}, {89.489, 21.1993, -498.41}, {89.4895,21.1993, -498.67}, {89.49, 21.1993, -500.9}, {89.4904,21.1993, -501.68}, {89.4909, 21.1993, -501.38}, {89.4914,21.1993, -499.46}, {89.4919, 21.1993, -497.69}, {89.4924,21.1993, -495.99}, {89.4929, 21.1993, -495.8}, {89.4933,21.1993, -495.69}, {89.4938, 21.1993, -495.79}, {89.4943,21.1993, -494.16}, {89.4948, 21.1993, -494.41}, {89.4953,21.1993, -494.5}, {89.4957, 21.1993, -494.66}, {89.4962,21.1993, -493.94}, {89.4967, 21.1993, -492.3}, {89.4972,21.1993, -492.02}, {89.4977, 21.1993, -491.28}, {89.4982,21.1993, -491.44}, {89.4986, 21.1993, -491.43}, {89.4991,21.1993, -491.09}, {89.4996, 21.1993, -489.91}, {89.5001,21.1993, -488.6}, {89.5006, 21.1993, -487.21}, {89.501, 21.1993, -488.38}, {89.5015, 21.1993, -488.66}, {89.502,21.1993, -487.37}, {89.5025, 21.1993, -485.33}, {89.503,21.1993, -483.74}, {89.5035, 21.1993, -481.36}, {89.5039,21.1993, -474.1}, {89.5044, 21.1993, -479.88}, {89.5049,21.1993, -482.34}, {89.5054, 21.1993, -482.2}, {89.5059,21.1993, -479.35}, {89.5063, 21.1993, -475.92}, {89.5068,21.1993, -472.48}, {89.5073, 21.1993, -470.56}, {89.5078,21.1993, -469.33}, {89.5083, 21.1993, -468.74}, {89.5088,21.1993, -468.36}, {89.5092, 21.1993, -465.16}, {89.5097,21.1993, -463.25}, {89.5102, 21.1993, -464.53}, {89.5107,21.1993, -460.09}, {89.5112, 21.1993, -460.18}, {89.5116,21.1993, -462.2}, {89.5121, 21.1993, -459.99}, {89.5126,21.1993, -458.27}, {89.5131, 21.1993, -457.85}, {89.5136,21.1993, -461.3}, {89.5141, 21.1993, -463.15}, {89.5145,21.1993, -461.02}, {89.515, 21.1993, -459.18}, {89.5155,21.1993, -461.43}, {89.516, 21.1993, -455.8}, {89.5165,21.1993, -456.52}, {89.5169, 21.1993, -456.72}, {89.5174,21.1993, -453.76}, {89.5179, 21.1993, -453.72}, {89.5184,21.1993, -453.07}, {89.5189, 21.1993, -449.64}, {89.5194,21.1993, -449.95}, {89.5198, 21.1993, -446.66}, {89.5203,21.1993, -446.04}, {89.5208, 21.1993, -445.47}, {89.5213,21.1993, -442.77}, {89.5218, 21.1993, -440.08}, {89.5222,21.1993, -437.42}, {89.5227, 21.1993, -436.32}, {89.5232,21.1993, -438.91}, {89.5237, 21.1993, -433.72}, {89.5242,21.1993, -426.86}, {89.5247, 21.1993, -427.96}, {89.5251,21.1993, -423.14}, {89.5256, 21.1993, -420.51}, {89.5261,21.1993, -429.66}, {89.5266, 21.1993, -425.39}, {89.5271,21.1993, -418.07}, {89.5275, 21.1993, -413.1}, {89.528, 21.1993, -410.11}, {89.5285, 21.1993, -409.46}, {89.529,21.1993, -406.79}, {89.5295, 21.1993, -406.7}, {89.53,21.1993, -402.07}, {89.5304, 21.1993, -398.77}, {89.5309,21.1993, -391.43}, {89.5314, 21.1993, -392.19}, {89.5319,21.1993, -389.13}, {89.5324, 21.1993, -384.87}, {89.5328,21.1993, -381.81}, {89.5333, 21.1993, -380.88}, {89.5338,21.1993, -382.14}, {89.5343, 21.1993, -376.79}, {89.5348,21.1993, -344.36}, {89.5353, 21.1993, -328.65}, {89.5357,21.1993, -317.24}, {89.5362, 21.1993, -305.93}, {89.5367,21.1993, -295.34}, {89.5372, 21.1993, -285.63}, {89.5377,21.1993, -276.51}, {89.5381, 21.1993, -267.49}, {89.5386,21.1993, -258.09}, {89.5391, 21.1993, -247.96}, {89.5396,21.1993, -237.}, {89.5401, 21.1993, -225.91}, {89.5406,21.1993, -215.25}, {89.541, 21.1993, -204.76}, {89.5415,21.1993, -194.08}, {89.542, 21.1993, -183.22}, {89.5425,21.1993, -172.28}, {89.543, 21.1993, -161.5}, {89.5434,21.1993, -151.56}, {89.5439, 21.1993, -142.9}, {89.5444,21.1993, -135.86}, {89.5449, 21.1993, -129.6}, {89.5454,21.1993, -130.55}, {89.5459, 21.1993, -130.28}, {89.5463,21.1993, -128.22}, {89.5468, 21.1993, -124.51}, {89.5473,21.1993, -123.43}, {89.5478, 21.1993, -121.79}, {89.5483,21.1993, -121.08}, {89.5487, 21.1993, -118.99}, {89.5492,21.1993, -118.06}, {89.5497, 21.1993, -117.1}, {89.5502,21.1993, -117.1}, {89.5507, 21.1993, -116.87}, {89.5512,21.1993, -116.26}, {89.5516, 21.1993, -115.53}, {89.5521,21.1993, -114.91}, {89.5526, 21.1993, -114.36}, {89.5531, 21.1993, -113.89}, {89.5536, 21.1993, -113.44}, {89.554,21.1993, -113.04}, {89.5545, 21.1993, -112.62}, {89.555, 21.1993, -112.14}, {89.5555, 21.1993, -111.87}, {89.6475,21.1993, -84.86}, {89.648, 21.1993, -84.82}, {89.6485,21.1993, -84.77}, {89.649, 21.1993, -84.72}, {89.6495,21.1993, -84.66}, {89.6499, 21.1993, -84.61}, {89.6504,21.1993, -84.54}, {89.6509, 21.1993, -84.48}, {89.6514,21.1993, -84.44}, {89.6519, 21.1993, -84.41}, {89.6523,21.1993, -84.36}, {89.6528, 21.1993, -84.21}, {89.6533,21.1993, -84.11}, {89.6538, 21.1993, -84.}, {89.6543,21.1993, -84.19}, {89.6548, 21.1993, -84.19}, {89.6552,21.1993, -84.01}, {89.6557, 21.1993, -84.04}, {89.6562,21.1993, -84.05}, {89.6567, 21.1993, -84.06}, {89.6572,21.1993, -84.06}, {89.6576, 21.1993, -84.05}, {89.6581,21.1993, -84.05}, {89.6745, 21.1993, -82.97}, {89.675,21.1993, -83.17}, {89.6755, 21.1993, -83.45}, {89.676,21.1993, -83.87}, {89.6764, 21.1993, -84.5}, {89.6769,21.1993, -85.42}, {89.6774, 21.1993, -86.54}, {89.6779,21.1993, -86.97}, {89.6784, 21.1993, -79.26}, {89.6788,21.1993, -81.78}, {89.6793, 21.1993, -80.87}, {89.6798,21.1993, -76.85}, {89.6803, 21.1993, -79.16}, {89.6808,21.1993, -80.5}, {89.6813, 21.1993, -81.03}, {89.6817,21.1993, -81.23}, {89.6822, 21.1993, -81.29}, {89.6827,21.1993, -81.33}, {89.2813, 21.1997, -463.61}, {89.2818,21.1997, -463.92}, {89.2823, 21.1997, -464.31}, {89.2828,21.1997, -464.7}, {89.2833, 21.1997, -464.98}, {89.2837,21.1997, -465.05}, {89.2842, 21.1997, -464.89}, {89.2847,21.1997, -465.45}, {89.2852, 21.1997, -468.32}, {89.2857,21.1997, -473.82}, {89.2861, 21.1997, -480.2}, {89.2866,21.1997, -484.9}, {89.2871, 21.1997, -486.89}, {89.2876,21.1997, -487.02}, {89.2881, 21.1997, -488.83}, {89.2886,21.1997, -490.4}, {89.289, 21.1997, -491.48}, {89.2895,21.1997, -493.76}, {89.29, 21.1997, -497.88}, {89.2905,21.1997, -497.59}, {89.291, 21.1997, -497.83}, {89.2914,21.1997, -496.79}, {89.2919, 21.1997, -489.64}, {89.2924,21.1997, -501.34}, {89.2929, 21.1997, -505.55}, {89.2934,21.1997, -499.35}, {89.2939, 21.1997, -496.44}, {89.2943,21.1997, -497.49}, {89.2948, 21.1997, -496.97}, {89.2953,21.1997, -502.82}, {89.2958, 21.1997, -496.24}, {89.2963,21.1997, -484.13}, {89.2967, 21.1997, -483.32}, {89.2972,21.1997, -487.19}, {89.2977, 21.1997, -490.1}, {89.2982,21.1997, -492.26}, {89.2987, 21.1997, -493.45}, {89.2992,21.1997, -495.51}, {89.2996, 21.1997, -499.69}, {89.3001,21.1997, -500.27}, {89.3006, 21.1997, -499.9}, {89.3011,21.1997, -500.73}, {89.3016, 21.1997, -500.31}, {89.302,21.1997, -501.05}, {89.3025, 21.1997, -499.91}, {89.303, 21.1997, -500.91}, {89.3035, 21.1997, -501.7}, {89.304,21.1997, -500.79}, {89.3045, 21.1997, -501.64}, {89.3049,21.1997, -501.71}, {89.3054, 21.1997, -502.}, {89.3059,21.1997, -502.38}, {89.3064, 21.1997, -502.81}, {89.3069, 21.1997, -503.26}, {89.3073, 21.1997, -503.75}, {89.3078, 21.1997,-504.52}, {89.3546, 21.1997, -537.36}, {89.355,21.1997, -537.9}, {89.3555, 21.1997, -538.55}, {89.356,21.1997, -539.27}, {89.3565, 21.1997, -540.02}, {89.357,21.1997, -540.76}, {89.3575, 21.1997, -541.41}, {89.3579,21.1997, -541.41}, {89.3584, 21.1997, -541.93}, {89.3589,21.1997, -542.34}, {89.3594, 21.1997, -543.91}, {89.3599,21.1997, -547.37}, {89.3603, 21.1997, -547.82}, {89.3608,21.1997, -546.95}, {89.3613, 21.1997, -546.71}, {89.3618,21.1997, -547.53}, {89.3623, 21.1997, -548.1}, {89.3628,21.1997, -546.}, {89.3632, 21.1997, -547.05}, {89.3637,21.1997, -547.49}, {89.3642, 21.1997, -545.05}, {89.3647,21.1997, -543.66}, {89.3652, 21.1997, -543.14}, {89.3656,21.1997, -543.21}, {89.3661, 21.1997, -542.16}, {89.3666,21.1997, -541.21}, {89.3671, 21.1997, -543.06}, {89.3676,21.1997, -541.72}, {89.3681, 21.1997, -538.62}, {89.3685,21.1997, -536.36}, {89.369, 21.1997, -529.56}, {89.3695,21.1997, -534.77}, {89.37, 21.1997, -533.53}, {89.3705,21.1997, -533.77}, {89.3709, 21.1997, -534.55}, {89.3714,21.1997, -534.51}, {89.3719, 21.1997, -535.04}, {89.3724,21.1997, -536.33}, {89.3729, 21.1997, -533.46}, {89.3734,21.1997, -532.52}, {89.3738, 21.1997, -532.76}, {89.3743,21.1997, -531.35}, {89.3748, 21.1997, -531.67}, {89.3753,21.1997, -532.5}, {89.3758, 21.1997, -532.07}, {89.3762,21.1997, -531.12}, {89.3767, 21.1997, -530.56}, {89.3772,21.1997, -529.08}, {89.3777, 21.1997, -529.33}, {89.3782,21.1997, -529.58}, {89.3787, 21.1997, -529.42}, {89.3791,21.1997, -529.57}, {89.3796, 21.1997, -530.22}, {89.3801,21.1997, -530.22}, {89.3806, 21.1997, -528.22}, {89.3811,21.1997, -529.02}, {89.3815, 21.1997, -529.28}, {89.382,21.1997, -523.11}, {89.3825, 21.1997, -518.85}, {89.383,21.1997, -515.61}, {89.3835, 21.1997, -512.38}, {89.384,21.1997, -512.62}, {89.3844, 21.1997, -512.44}, {89.3849,21.1997, -507.95}, {89.3854, 21.1997, -509.07}, {89.3859,21.1997, -507.64}, {89.3864, 21.1997, -507.33}, {89.3868,21.1997, -508.48}, {89.3873, 21.1997, -507.77}, {89.3878,21.1997, -508.7}, {89.3883, 21.1997, -508.24}, {89.3888,21.1997, -506.37}, {89.3893, 21.1997, -504.5}, {89.3897,21.1997, -505.18}, {89.3902, 21.1997, -504.43}, {89.3907,21.1997, -505.13}, {89.3912, 21.1997, -506.51}, {89.3917,21.1997, -505.78}, {89.3921, 21.1997, -506.47}, {89.3926,21.1997, -508.3}, {89.3931, 21.1997, -509.26}, {89.3936,21.1997, -511.22}, {89.3941, 21.1997, -514.62}, {89.3946,21.1997, -516.28}, {89.395, 21.1997, -512.29}, {89.3955,21.1997, -507.35}, {89.396, 21.1997, -506.79}, {89.3965,21.1997, -503.78}, {89.397, 21.1997, -504.09}, {89.3974,21.1997, -506.43}, {89.3979, 21.1997, -508.2}, {89.3984,21.1997, -510.04}, {89.3989, 21.1997, -510.98}, {89.3994,21.1997, -512.74}, {89.3999, 21.1997, -513.29}, {89.4003,21.1997, -514.19}, {89.4008, 21.1997, -515.1}, {89.4013,21.1997, -516.19}, {89.4018, 21.1997, -517.11}, {89.4023,21.1997, -516.69}, {89.4027, 21.1997, -517.34}, {89.4032,21.1997, -516.87}, {89.4037, 21.1997, -517.12}, {89.4042, 21.1997, -520.02}, {89.4047, 21.1997, -521.39}, {89.4052,21.1997, -524.02}, {89.4056, 21.1997, -527.46}, {89.4061,21.1997, -527.89}, {89.4066, 21.1997, -527.81}, {89.4071,21.1997, -526.72}, {89.4076, 21.1997, -529.37}, {89.408,21.1997, -527.5}, {89.4085, 21.1997, -526.14}, {89.409,21.1997, -525.25}, {89.4095, 21.1997, -525.2}, {89.41,21.1997, -526.53}, {89.4105, 21.1997, -527.47}, {89.4109,21.1997, -526.73}, {89.4114, 21.1997, -527.5}, {89.4119,21.1997, -528.86}, {89.4124, 21.1997, -530.64}, {89.4129,21.1997, -534.67}, {89.4133, 21.1997, -537.84}, {89.4138,21.1997, -539.41}, {89.4143, 21.1997, -539.58}, {89.4148,21.1997, -538.79}, {89.4153, 21.1997, -538.01}, {89.4158,21.1997, -538.44}, {89.4162, 21.1997, -539.41}, {89.4167,21.1997, -539.62}, {89.4172, 21.1997, -540.62}, {89.4177,21.1997, -540.45}, {89.4182, 21.1997, -539.77}, {89.4186,21.1997, -538.29}, {89.4191, 21.1997, -539.03}, {89.4196,21.1997, -537.77}, {89.4201, 21.1997, -536.62}, {89.4206,21.1997, -537.06}, {89.4211, 21.1997, -536.94}, {89.4215,21.1997, -536.86}, {89.422, 21.1997, -536.77}, {89.4225,21.1997, -538.54}, {89.423, 21.1997, -536.91}, {89.4235,21.1997, -537.47}, {89.4239, 21.1997, -535.32}, {89.4244,21.1997, -535.73}, {89.4249, 21.1997, -533.87}, {89.4254,21.1997, -531.15}, {89.4259, 21.1997, -534.88}, {89.4264,21.1997, -534.76}, {89.4268, 21.1997, -532.12}, {89.4273,21.1997, -533.13}, {89.4278, 21.1997, -532.56}, {89.4283,21.1997, -532.21}, {89.4288, 21.1997, -529.29}, {89.4293,21.1997, -530.16}, {89.4297, 21.1997, -530.61}, {89.4302,21.1997, -531.51}, {89.4307, 21.1997, -532.46}, {89.4312,21.1997, -531.57}, {89.4317, 21.1997, -530.38}, {89.4321,21.1997, -531.29}, {89.4326, 21.1997, -531.84}, {89.4331,21.1997, -532.45}, {89.4336, 21.1997, -533.38}, {89.4341,21.1997, -530.03}, {89.4346, 21.1997, -529.5}, {89.435,21.1997, -530.46}, {89.4355, 21.1997, -529.94}, {89.436,21.1997, -530.15}, {89.4365, 21.1997, -530.}, {89.437,21.1997, -530.1}, {89.4374, 21.1997, -530.65}, {89.4379,21.1997, -530.77}, {89.4384, 21.1997, -530.68}, {89.4389,21.1997, -529.95}, {89.4394, 21.1997, -530.49}, {89.4399,21.1997, -530.76}, {89.4403, 21.1997, -530.05}, {89.4408,21.1997, -530.41}, {89.4413, 21.1997, -531.92}, {89.4418,21.1997, -532.89}, {89.4423, 21.1997, -533.33}, {89.4427,  21.1997, -533.27}, {89.4432, 21.1997, -533.53}, {89.4437,21.1997, -534.08}, {89.4442, 21.1997, -533.69}, {89.4447,21.1997, -535.26}, {89.4452, 21.1997, -534.9}, {89.4456,21.1997, -536.48}, {89.4461, 21.1997, -537.34}, {89.4466,21.1997, -536.43}, {89.4471, 21.1997, -535.21}, {89.4476,21.1997, -538.82}, {89.448, 21.1997, -537.92}, {89.4485,21.1997, -538.11}, {89.449, 21.1997, -538.91}, {89.4495,21.1997, -536.78}, {89.45, 21.1997, -533.83}, {89.4505,21.1997, -532.17}, {89.4509, 21.1997, -533.33}, {89.4514,21.1997, -532.34}, {89.4519, 21.1997, -532.55}, {89.4524,21.1997, -531.55}, {89.4529, 21.1997, -529.89}, {89.4533,21.1997, -528.65}, {89.4538, 21.1997, -528.49}, {89.4543,21.1997, -529.12}, {89.4548, 21.1997, -528.59}, {89.4553,21.1997, -528.05}, {89.4558, 21.1997, -527.64}, {89.4562,21.1997, -527.11}, {89.4567, 21.1997, -527.23}, {89.4572,21.1997, -525.96}, {89.4577, 21.1997, -524.91}, {89.4582,21.1997, -524.73}, {89.4586, 21.1997, -524.06}, {89.4591,21.1997, -523.46}, {89.4596, 21.1997, -524.11}, {89.4601,21.1997, -524.42}, {89.4606, 21.1997, -526.37}, {89.4611,21.1997, -526.97}, {89.4615, 21.1997, -525.16}, {89.462,21.1997, -523.56}, {89.4625, 21.1997, -521.66}, {89.463,21.1997, -520.22}, {89.4635, 21.1997, -518.52}, {89.4639,21.1997, -518.11}, {89.4644, 21.1997, -518.9}, {89.4649,21.1997, -518.85}, {89.4654, 21.1997, -519.15}, {89.4659,21.1997, -516.93}, {89.4664, 21.1997, -516.57}, {89.4668,21.1997, -517.12}, {89.4673, 21.1997, -519.45}, {89.4678,21.1997, -521.41}, {89.4683, 21.1997, -519.68}, {89.4688,21.1997, -518.64}, {89.4692, 21.1997, -517.18}, {89.4697,  21.1997, -517.13}, {89.4702, 21.1997, -516.81}, {89.4707,21.1997, -517.02}, {89.4712, 21.1997, -517.39}, {89.4717,21.1997, -517.74}, {89.4721, 21.1997, -517.2}, {89.4726,21.1997, -520.47}, {89.4731, 21.1997, -521.51}, {89.4736,21.1997, -520.58}, {89.4741, 21.1997, -519.5}, {89.4745,21.1997, -519.32}, {89.475, 21.1997, -519.83}, {89.4755,21.1997, -520.5}, {89.476, 21.1997, -520.95}, {89.4765,21.1997, -520.42}, {89.477, 21.1997, -518.09}, {89.4774,21.1997, -517.07}, {89.4779, 21.1997, -516.76}, {89.4784,21.1997, -517.64}, {89.4789, 21.1997, -517.93}, {89.4794,21.1997, -517.8}, {89.4798, 21.1997, -518.22}, {89.4803,21.1997, -517.24}, {89.4808, 21.1997, -514.29}, {89.4813,21.1997, -510.45}, {89.4818, 21.1997, -508.94}, {89.4823,21.1997, -508.65}, {89.4827, 21.1997, -507.34}, {89.4832,21.1997, -506.55}, {89.4837, 21.1997, -508.2}, {89.4842,21.1997, -507.82}, {89.4847, 21.1997, -505.93}, {89.4851,21.1997, -504.6}, {89.4856, 21.1997, -503.65}, {89.4861,21.1997, -502.15}, {89.4866, 21.1997, -504.3}, {89.4871,21.1997, -502.04}, {89.4876, 21.1997, -503.21}, {89.488,21.1997, -503.22}, {89.4885, 21.1997, -501.69}, {89.489,21.1997, -502.15}, {89.4895, 21.1997, -498.93}, {89.49,21.1997, -501.41}, {89.4904, 21.1997, -504.28}, {89.4909,21.1997, -504.94}, {89.4914, 21.1997, -500.76}, {89.4919,21.1997, -498.68}, {89.4924, 21.1997, -495.91}, {89.4929,21.1997, -494.95}, {89.4933, 21.1997, -495.21}, {89.4938,21.1997, -495.62}, {89.4943, 21.1997, -494.25}, {89.4948,21.1997, -494.09}, {89.4953, 21.1997, -494.66}, {89.4957,21.1997, -493.79}, {89.4962, 21.1997, -495.52}, {89.4967,21.1997, -493.45}, {89.4972, 21.1997, -491.72}, {89.4977,21.1997, -490.53}, {89.4982, 21.1997, -490.16}, {89.4986,21.1997, -490.63}, {89.4991, 21.1997, -490.93}, {89.4996,21.1997, -490.35}, {89.5001, 21.1997, -489.4}, {89.5006,21.1997, -488.55}, {89.501, 21.1997, -488.66}, {89.5015,21.1997, -488.88}, {89.502, 21.1997, -488.3}, {89.5025,21.1997, -487.12}, {89.503, 21.1997, -485.67}, {89.5035,21.1997, -483.71}, {89.5039, 21.1997, -479.92}, {89.5044,21.1997, -478.76}, {89.5049, 21.1997, -485.55}, {89.5054,21.1997, -487.23}, {89.5059, 21.1997, -481.67}, {89.5063,21.1997, -477.04}, {89.5068, 21.1997, -471.33}, {89.5073,21.1997, -470.49}, {89.5078, 21.1997, -472.15}, {89.5083,21.1997, -469.48}, {89.5088, 21.1997, -467.63}, {89.5092,21.1997, -468.65}, {89.5097, 21.1997, -467.13}, {89.5102,21.1997, -464.38}, {89.5107, 21.1997, -464.47}, {89.5112,21.1997, -460.19}, {89.5116, 21.1997, -459.89}, {89.5121,21.1997, -457.58}, {89.5126, 21.1997, -458.11}, {89.5131,21.1997, -460.12}, {89.5136, 21.1997, -461.02}, {89.5141,21.1997, -462.13}, {89.5145, 21.1997, -460.31}, {89.515,21.1997, -457.71}, {89.5155, 21.1997, -458.5}, {89.516,21.1997, -460.28}, {89.5165, 21.1997, -459.7}, {89.5169,21.1997, -455.66}, {89.5174, 21.1997, -452.89}, {89.5179,21.1997, -446.65}, {89.5184, 21.1997, -447.99}, {89.5189,21.1997, -445.26}, {89.5194, 21.1997, -445.85}, {89.5198,21.1997, -447.33}, {89.5203, 21.1997, -445.55}, {89.5208,21.1997, -445.19}, {89.5213, 21.1997, -445.31}, {89.5218,21.1997, -441.5}, {89.5222, 21.1997, -441.51}, {89.5227,21.1997, -439.34}, {89.5232, 21.1997, -443.93}, {89.5237,21.1997, -428.97}, {89.5242, 21.1997, -427.45}, {89.5247,21.1997, -430.78}, {89.5251, 21.1997, -423.1}, {89.5256,21.1997, -422.84}, {89.5261, 21.1997, -421.94}, {89.5266,21.1997, -414.83}, {89.5271, 21.1997, -411.23}, {89.5275,21.1997, -413.19}, {89.528, 21.1997, -409.24}, {89.5285,21.1997, -406.45}, {89.529, 21.1997, -407.74}, {89.5295,21.1997, -402.01}, {89.53, 21.1997, -401.97}, {89.5304,21.1997, -398.84}, {89.5309, 21.1997, -395.89}, {89.5314,21.1997, -392.59}, {89.5319, 21.1997, -390.9}, {89.5324,21.1997, -388.74}, {89.5328, 21.1997, -386.16}, {89.5333,21.1997, -381.92}, {89.5338, 21.1997, -377.19}, {89.5343,21.1997, -358.84}, {89.5348, 21.1997, -346.08}, {89.5353,21.1997, -336.55}, {89.5357, 21.1997, -326.75}, {89.5362,21.1997, -312.73}}
```

I have converted the geographic coordinate into UTM as

```
GeoGridPosition[
  GeoPosition[{DataGeo},"WGS84"], 
  {"UTMZone46",  "CentralScaleFactor" -> 0.9996, "GridOrigin" -> {500000, 0}}]
```

> ```
> GeoGridPosition[
>     {{
>       {448254.,9.98095*10^6,-457.58},{448305.,9.98097*10^6,-458.11}, 
>       {448356.,9.98099*10^6,-460.12}}}, 
>      UTMZone46, WGS84]
> ```

and now I would like to:

1. make a new list as

   ```
   DataUTM = {{longUTM, LatUTM, depth}, ... }
   ```
2. efficiently plot the grid. Maybe as Image3D, but I don't understand how to set the "slice" requested in the background settings.
3. calculate the volume enclosed between the grid and the sea surface

I apologize for an aborted posting attempt and I will be happy to improve the question helping you to help me!

Comment: Your data sample all has the same latitude which makes it difficult to play with in any meaningful way. Could you post a different sample which is more grid-like?

Comment: Hallo Simon, I added a larger sample, hoping this is more meaningful. It is hard to cut the grid in a way that still makes sense. I have also made a shallow water sample as the grid is collected across a continental margin but I exceed the amount of allowed characters, so I couldn't add it!

Comment: A suggestion, in order to prevent any possible clashes with Mathematica,in terms of veriable definition, it is recommended to use a different naming convention. Please see: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18395#18395 for more information.